# Interface Builder crash with:Assertion Message: Interface Builder encountered an error communicating with the iPhone Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios4, interface-builder

Yesterday was working on a iPhone app with a tab bar when suddenly IB started to crash with the following reason:

> Assertion Message: Interface Builder encountered an error communicating with the iPhone Simulator. If you choose to file a crash report or radar for this issue, please check Console.app for crash reports for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" and include their content in your crash report.

I've tried to check the following:

- start with an empty standard Tab Bar project template. It crash
- uninstall XCode et all
- clean any old file left around
- reinstall it
- restore from an old backup XCode

Nothing of the above have worked :( Anyone of you could give me some suggestion on how to proceed?
I'm on Snow Leopard and using `XCode 3.2.5 and SDK 4.3` (no other SDK for iDevice is installed).
BTW I can run with no problem Simulator...

Below the full trace of exception:

> 06/05/11 10.07.15  Interface Builder[1804] Assertion Failure: NO
>   06/05/11 10.07.15   Interface Builder[1804] File: /SourceCache/IBCocoaTouchPlugin/IBCocoaTouchPlugin-132/IBPlugin/Utilities/IBObjectMarshalling.m
>   06/05/11 10.07.15   Interface Builder[1804] Line: 351
>   06/05/11 10.07.15   Interface Builder[1804] Backtrace:
>   
> 0   IBCocoaTouchPlugin               0x000000010e723907 IBMarshallObjectAndAskValueForKeyPathUsingResultMarshallerWithContext + 525
>   
> 1   IBCocoaTouchPlugin               0x000000010e77911c IBIsManagedByTabBarController + 5744
>   
> 2   IBCocoaTouchPlugin               0x000000010e778bc4 IBIsManagedByTabBarController + 4376
>   
> 3   IBCocoaTouchPlugin               0x000000010e771e26 IBIsIBObjectURL + 25031
>   
> 4   IBCocoaTouchPlugin               0x000000010e766682 IBConfigureToolbar + 25129
>   
> 5   InterfaceBuilderKit              0x0000000100150151 -[IBEditor(DrawingMethods) setDecorationsNeedDisplayForObject:] + 370
>   
> 6   InterfaceBuilderKit              0x000000010013fa84 -[IBEditor setShowingSelection:] + 175
>   
> 7   InterfaceBuilderKit              0x000000010013f978 -[IBEditor didActivate] + 32
>   
> 8   InterfaceBuilderKit              0x000000010014f847 -[IBViewEditor didActivate] + 43
>   
> 9   InterfaceBuilderKit              0x00000001001ddb13 -[IBEditorManager openEditorForObject:closingSubEditors:makeKey:] + 1458
>   
> 10  InterfaceBuilderKit              0x00000001001d2d4a -[IBDocument openEditorForObject:closingSubEditors:makeKeyAndOrderFront:] + 432
>   
> 11  InterfaceBuilderKit              0x000000010013d605 -[IBDocument openEditorForObject:makeKeyAndOrderFront:] + 27
>   
> 12  InterfaceBuilderKit              0x0000000100130315 -[IBDocument makeWindowControllers] + 498
>   
> 13  AppKit                           0x00007fff8708b4e6 -[NSDocumentController _finishOpeningDocument:andShowWindows:] + 54
>   
> 14  AppKit                           0x00007fff8708ff41 -[NSDocumentController openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:display:error:] + 807
>   
> 15  InterfaceBuilderKit              0x00000001001732b6 -[IBDocumentController openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:display:error:] + 717
>   
> 16  AppKit                           0x00007fff8708f5f2 -[NSDocumentController _openDocumentsWithContentsOfURLs:display:presentErrors:] + 3457
>   
> 17  AppKit                           0x00007fff86f86b3d -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenDocumentsForURLs:] + 864
>   
> 18  AppKit                           0x00007fff86e5300d -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleCoreEvent:withReplyEvent:] + 217
>   
> 19  Foundation                       0x00007fff82bbee42 -[NSAppleEventManager dispatchRawAppleEvent:withRawReply:handlerRefCon:] + 360
>   
> 20  Foundation                       0x00007fff82bbec72 _NSAppleEventManagerGenericHandler + 114
>   
> 21  AE                               0x00007fff82074323 aeDispatchAppleEvent(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*, unsigned int, unsigned char*) + 162
>   
> 22  AE                               0x00007fff8207421c dispatchEventAndSendReply(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*) + 32
>   
> 23  AE                               0x00007fff82074123 aeProcessAppleEvent + 210
>   
> 24  HIToolbox                        0x00007fff80486619 AEProcessAppleEvent + 48
>   
> 25  AppKit                           0x00007fff86d5804b _DPSNextEvent + 1205
>   
> 26  AppKit                           0x00007fff86d577a9 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 155
>   
> 27  Interface Builder                0x00000001000038e0
>   
> 28  AppKit                           0x00007fff86f92c47 -[NSApplication _realDoModalLoop:peek:] + 442
>   
> 29  AppKit                           0x00007fff86f907d5 -[NSApplication runModalForWindow:] + 129
>   
> 30  InterfaceBuilderKit              0x00000001002742f1 -[IBDetailedAlert runModal] + 74
>   
> 31  Interface Builder                0x0000000100006fbd
>   
> 32  Interface Builder                0x0000000100007023
>   
> 33  IBCocoaTouchPlugin               0x000000010e721ffb IBMessageForAssertingMarshallingFailureFromException + 538
>   
> 34  Foundation                       0x00007fff82ba832f __NSThreadPerformPerform + 219
>   
> 35  CoreFoundation                   0x00007fff8082c401 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 1361
>   
> 36  CoreFoundation                   0x00007fff8082a5f9 __CFRunLoopRun + 873
>   
> 37  CoreFoundation                   0x00007fff80829dbf CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 575
>   
> 38  HIToolbox                        0x00007fff804807ee RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 333
>   
> 39  HIToolbox                        0x00007fff80480551 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 148
>   
> 40  HIToolbox                        0x00007fff804804ac BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 59
>   
> 41  AppKit                           0x00007fff86d57e64 _DPSNextEvent + 718
>   
> 42  AppKit                           0x00007fff86d577a9 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 155
>   
> 43  Interface Builder                0x00000001000038e0
>   
> 44  AppKit                           0x00007fff86f92c47 -[NSApplication _realDoModalLoop:peek:] + 442
>   
> 45  AppKit                           0x00007fff86f907d5 -[NSApplication runModalForWindow:] + 129
>   
> 46  InterfaceBuilderKit              0x00000001002742f1 -[IBDetailedAlert runModal] + 74
>   
> 47  Interface Builder                0x0000000100006fbd
>   
> 48  Interface Builder                0x0000000100007023
>   
> 49  IBCocoaTouchPlugin               0x000000010e721ffb IBMessageForAssertingMarshallingFailureFromException + 538
>   
> 50  Foundation                       0x00007fff82ba832f __NSThreadPerformPerform + 219
>   
> 51  CoreFoundation                   0x00007fff8082c401 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 1361
>   
> 52  CoreFoundation                   0x00007fff8082a5f9 __CFRunLoopRun + 873
>   
> 53  CoreFoundation                   0x00007fff80829dbf CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 575
>   
> 54  HIToolbox                        0x00007fff804807ee RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 333
>   
> 55  HIToolbox                        0x00007fff80480551 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 148
>   
> 56  HIToolbox                        0x00007fff804804ac BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 59
>   
> 57  AppKit                           0x00007fff86d57e64 _DPSNextEvent + 718
>   
> 58  AppKit                           0x00007fff86d577a9 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 155
>   
> 59  Interface Builder                0x00000001000038e0
>   
> 60  AppKit                           0x00007fff86f92c47 -[NSApplication _realDoModalLoop:peek:] + 442
>   
> 61  AppKit                           0x00007fff86f907d5 -[NSApplication runModalForWindow:] + 129
>   
> 62  InterfaceBuilderKit              0x00000001002742f1 -[IBDetailedAlert runModal] + 74
>   
> 63  Interface Builder                0x0000000100006fbd
>   
> 64  Interface Builder                0x0000000100007023
>   
> 65  IBCocoaTouchPlugin               0x000000010e721ffb IBMessageForAssertingMarshallingFailureFromException + 538
>   
> 66  Foundation                       0x00007fff82ba832f __NSThreadPerformPerform + 219
>   
> 67  CoreFoundation                   0x00007fff8082c401 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 1361
>   
> 68  CoreFoundation                   0x00007fff8082a5f9 __CFRunLoopRun + 873
>   
> 69  CoreFoundation                   0x00007fff80829dbf CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 575
>   
> 70  HIToolbox                        0x00007fff804807ee RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 333
>   
> 71  HIToolbox                        0x00007fff804805f3 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 310
>   
> 72  HIToolbox                        0x00007fff804804ac BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 59
>   
> 73  AppKit                           0x00007fff86d57e64 _DPSNextEvent + 718
>   
> 74  AppKit                           0x00007fff86d577a9 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 155
>   
> 75  Interface Builder                0x00000001000038e0
>   
> 76  AppKit                           0x00007fff86f92c47 -[NSApplication _realDoModalLoop:peek:] + 442
>   
> 77  AppKit                           0x00007fff86f907d5 -[NSApplication runModalForWindow:] + 129
>   
> 78  InterfaceBuilderKit              0x00000001002742f1 -[IBDetailedAlert runModal] + 74
>   
> 79  Interface Builder                0x0000000100006fbd
>   
> 80  Interface Builder                0x0000000100007023
>   
> 81  IBCocoaTouchPlugin               0x000000010e721ffb IBMessageForAssertingMarshallingFailureFromException + 538
>   
> 82  Foundation                       0x00007fff82ba832f __NSThreadPerformPerform + 219
>   
> 83  CoreFoundation                   0x00007fff8082c401 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 1361
>   
> 84  CoreFoundation                   0x00007fff8082a5f9 __CFRunLoopRun + 873
>   
> 85  CoreFoundation                   0x00007fff80829dbf CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 575
>   
> 86  HIToolbox                        0x00007fff804807ee RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 333
>   
> 87  HIToolbox                        0x00007fff80480551 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 148
>   
> 88  HIToolbox                        0x00007fff804804ac BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 59
>   
> 89  AppKit                           0x00007fff86d57e64 _DPSNextEvent + 718
>   
> 90  AppKit                           0x00007fff86d577a9 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 155
>   
> 91  Interface Builder                0x00000001000038e0
>   
> 92  AppKit                           0x00007fff86f92c47 -[NSApplication _realDoModalLoop:peek:] + 442
>   
> 93  AppKit                           0x00007fff86f907d5 -[NSApplication runModalForWindow:] + 129
>   
> 94  InterfaceBuilderKit              0x00000001002742f1 -[IBDetailedAlert runModal] + 74
>   
> 95  Interface Builder                0x0000000100006fbd
>   
> 96  Interface Builder                0x0000000100007023
>   
> 97  IBCocoaTouchPlugin               0x000000010e721ffb IBMessageForAssertingMarshallingFailureFromException + 538
>   
> 98  IBCocoaTouchPlugin               0x000000010e723907 IBMarshallObjectAndAskValueForKeyPathUsingResultMarshallerWithContext + 525
>   
> 99  IBCocoaTouchPlugin               0x000000010e77911c IBIsManagedByTabBarController + 5744
>   
> 100 IBCocoaTouchPlugin               0x000000010e778bc4 IBIsManagedByTabBarController + 4376
>   
> 101 IBCocoaTouchPlugin               0x000000010e771e26 IBIsIBObjectURL + 25031
>   
> 102 IBCocoaTouchPlugin               0x000000010e766682 IBConfigureToolbar + 25129
>   
> 103 InterfaceBuilderKit              0x0000000100150151 -[IBEditor(DrawingMethods) setDecorationsNeedDisplayForObject:] + 370
>   
> 104 InterfaceBuilderKit              0x000000010013fa84 -[IBEditor setShowingSelection:] + 175
>   
> 105 InterfaceBuilderKit              0x000000010013f978 -[IBEditor didActivate] + 32
>   
> 106 InterfaceBuilderKit              0x000000010014f847 -[IBViewEditor didActivate] + 43
>   
> 107 InterfaceBuilderKit              0x00000001001ddb13 -[IBEditorManager openEditorForObject:closingSubEditors:makeKey:] + 1458
>   
> 108 InterfaceBuilderKit              0x00000001001d2d4a -[IBDocument openEditorForObject:closingSubEditors:makeKeyAndOrderFront:] + 432
>   
> 109 InterfaceBuilderKit              0x000000010013d605 -[IBDocument openEditorForObject:makeKeyAndOrderFront:] + 27
>   
> 110 InterfaceBuilderKit              0x0000000100130315 -[IBDocument makeWindowControllers] + 498
>   
> 111 AppKit                           0x00007fff8708b4e6 -[NSDocumentController _finishOpeningDocument:andShowWindows:] + 54
>   
> 112 AppKit                           0x00007fff8708ff41 -[NSDocumentController openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:display:error:] + 807
>   
> 113 InterfaceBuilderKit              0x00000001001732b6 -[IBDocumentController openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:display:error:] + 717
>   
> 114 AppKit                           0x00007fff8708f5f2 -[NSDocumentController _openDocumentsWithContentsOfURLs:display:presentErrors:] + 3457
>   
> 115 AppKit                           0x00007fff86f86b3d -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenDocumentsForURLs:] + 864
>   
> 116 AppKit                           0x00007fff86e5300d -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleCoreEvent:withReplyEvent:] + 217
>   
> 117 Foundation                       0x00007fff82bbee42 -[NSAppleEventManager dispatchRawAppleEvent:withRawReply:handlerRefCon:] + 360
>   
> 118 Foundation                       0x00007fff82bbec72 _NSAppleEventManagerGenericHandler + 114
>   
> 119 AE                               0x00007fff82074323 aeDispatchAppleEvent(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*, unsigned int, unsigned char*) + 162
>   
> 120 AE                               0x00007fff8207421c dispatchEventAndSendReply(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*) + 32
>   
> 121 AE                               0x00007fff82074123 aeProcessAppleEvent + 210
>   
> 122 HIToolbox                        0x00007fff80486619 AEProcessAppleEvent + 48
>   
> 123 AppKit                           0x00007fff86d5804b _DPSNextEvent + 1205
>   
> 124 AppKit                           0x00007fff86d577a9 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 155
>   
> 125 Interface Builder                0x00000001000038e0
>   
> 126 AppKit                           0x00007fff86d1d48b -[NSApplication run] + 395
>   
> 127 AppKit                           0x00007fff86d161a8 NSApplicationMain + 364
>   
> 128 Interface Builder                0x0000000100001c44
>
> 06/05/11 10.07.15  Interface Builder[1804] Message: Interface Builder encountered an error communicating with the iPhone Simulator. If you choose to file a crash report or radar for this issue, please check Console.app for crash reports for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" and include their content in your crash report.
>
> Failed to determine the value for itemFramesArray of IBUITabBar.
>
> Exception name: NSObjectInaccessibleException
>   Exception reason: NSDistantObject (0x10f401430) is invalid (no connection)
>   Exception backtrace: 
>   (null)
>   Exception info:(null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1898678?threadID=1898678&tstart=1)

> Some similar cases reported were
>   solved by cleaning out an older
>   version of the SDK. That might work
>   for you if you installed over any
>   previous version of the SDK (even if
>   it was only for OS/X). You'll want to
>   uninstall as much as you can, new and
>   old. Then rename the Developer folder
>   so the next installation will make a
>   new one. Your objective should be to
>   prepare your Mac for a clean install,
>   as if it had never hosted any
>   development software in the past.
>   After you've hosed out as much as you
>   can, install the SDK again.
>
> 1. Uninstalled the previous SDK using sudo
>      /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools
>      --mode=all from the terminal.
> 2. Changed the name of the Developer dir.
> 3. Changed my time zone to USA and my language to English from Hebrew.
> 4. Installed the 10.5.6 combo update from Apple's site.
> 5. Restarted
> 6. Reinstalled the SDK
> 7. ALL IS GOOD

Comment: Yep I've done something similar and indeed worked out... however now it happened again :( But I've noticed that the error showed up again after I've opened a sample project that was containing some old SDK target that I do not have installed of course. It seems that just opening it is enough to break my project. Any idea of why this is creating problem?

Comment: I'm not really sure about is wrong with my project but I can say that same XIB that is failing into XCode3 is working properly into XCode4. So I may suppose that there's some issue into IB released with XCode3. I'm not an expert and cannot dig to much but that is my experience.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:
I had the same problem and I found that if I change my deployment target from iOS 4.0 to iOS 4.3 it just works fine for me and keeping Base SDK 5.0.